# WAJP to display message based on age

Tags: java

WAJP program which displays a different message depending on the age given. Here are the possible responses:

`age is less than 16, say "You can't drive."`

`age is less than 18, say "You can't vote."`

`age is less than 25, say "You can't rent a car."`

`age is 25 or over, say "You can do anything that's legal."`

Here's a sample run. Notice that a person who is under 16 will display three messages, one for being under 16, one for also being under 18, and one for also being under 25.

Comment: This seems to be like a homework question. Have you tried working on it?

Answer (score 0):

4 basic `if-statements` will solve the problem, as you want to output all the possible messages if the age input meets any of the four requirements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an age: ");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

        if (age < 16)
        {
            System.out.println("You can't drive.");
        }
        if (age < 18)
        {
            System.out.println("You can't vote.");
        }
        if (age < 25)
        {
            System.out.println("You can't rent a car.");
        }
        if (age >= 25) 
        {
            System.out.println("You can do anything that's legal.");
        }
    }
}
```